# How to remove dot followed by non digit or any special character?

Tags: javascript

Example: `ABCD, N.C. exg. 58/2095, s.2.7 A. 2A.` is the text and am using Regexp

> `String.replace(/([a-z]+).|.([ ?!\d])/ig, '$1')

O/p : Missing some Text from the Text.

> Expected is: `ABCD, NC exg 58/2095, s.2.7 A2A`

--dot followed by non digit(special Char or Alphabets)  should replace with null.

Comment: Why did you deface your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternation and grouping.

`([a-z]+)\.` - Matches one or more character (captures as group) followed by dot.

`\.([a-z]+)` - Matches dot followed by one or more character (captures chracters as group)

And in replace by the matched group.

```js
let str = `ABCD, N.C. exg. 58/2095, s. 2.7 `

let op = str.replace(/([a-z]+)\.|\.([a-z]+)/ig, '$1')

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is only ASCII, just replace every letter followed by a dot with the character itself:

```js
console.log(
  "ABCD, N.C. exg. 58/2095, s. 2.7".replace(/([a-z])\./ig, '$1') 
);
```

> Removing every special character.

Because that's what you are telling it to do. `[^\w.\s]` matches every character that is not a letter, number, `_`, `.` or white space.

Comment: This won't replace `this .s  xyz`

Comment: @CodeManiac: Sure, but that's not in the OP's requirements.

Comment: Yeah not explicitly but as in pattern i see it's removing `this s. xyz` so i thought this case should also be handled. don't mind just trying to learn more out of this awesome community. anyways nice answer :)